# Cannot mounting to /dev/sdaX in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I run `fdisk -l /dev/sda`, I got

[image]

I execute `mdadm --examine /dev/sda4`, I got

[image]

When trying to mount `mount /dev/sda4 /home/mydata/`, I got:

> mount: /home/mydata: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'.

I tried also `mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md4  /dev/sda4 --force`

I got

> mdadm: /dev/sda4 is busy - skipping

I ran `cat /proc/mdstat`

[image]

**How to mount my `/home/mydata` to `/dev/sda4/` ?**

Comment: Most likely, the RAID in question is already running - run `cat /proc/mdstat`and post the results

Comment: @EugenRieck I updated my post with screen

Comment: As you see, `/dev/sda4` is already part of `/dev/md3` array. You can mount `/dev/md3` to access your data, but be aware that there is a resync outstanding.

Comment: What does mean resync ? I'm newbie :) I'm trying  to understand dedi server with stuff

Comment: Your data is stored in a mirrored set of two hard drives, i.e. a RAID1. Most likely due to an unexpected shutdown this mirror set is not guaranteed to be really a perfect mirror. The system will automatically check every single byte of the array, to find and if possible fix differences. While this is transparent to your use of the array, it is expected to slow it down a lot.